# Trying to create an convolutional autoencoder network in Keras, but, the autoencoder.fit() function is giving me an error

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to create an convolutional autoencoder network in Keras, but, the autoencoder.fit() function is giving me an error that 'logits' and 'labels' must have the same shape. I'm not sure what 'logits' is referring to, and I don't think I'm passing labels into the fit? If so, I don't quite see where ... Can someone see what is spawning this error?

```
data = tf.keras.utils.image_dataset_from_directory('/content/gdrive/MyDrive/Skyrmion Vision/testFiles/train/',batch_size=32,image_size=(237,237),shuffle=False)
data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()

#get another batch from the iterator
batch = data_iterator.next()

len(batch) # theres the images and theres the labels -- images are represented as numpy arrays

batch[0].shape

batch[1]

#different based on what the data_iterator grabs
fig, ax = plt.subplots(ncols=4, figsize=(20,20))
for idx, img in enumerate(batch[0][:4]):
    ax[idx].imshow(img.astype(int))
    ax[idx].title.set_text(batch[1][idx])

"""## **SCALE DATA**"""
# functions available to apply to pipeline, this is using the map() function: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset
data = data.map(lambda x,y: (x/255, y))
scaled_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = scaled_iterator.next()[0]
batch[0].max()

"""## **Split Data**"""

len(data) # 127 batches, each batch with 32 images
train_size = int(len(data)*.7)+2
val_size = int(len(data)*.2)
test_size = int(len(data)*.1)
print(train_size,val_size,test_size)
train_size+val_size+test_size

# from  https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset
train = data.take(train_size)
val = data.skip(train_size).take(val_size)
test = data.skip(train_size+val_size).take(test_size)
len(train)

"""## **DEEP MODEL**"""
from keras.layers import Input, Dense, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, UpSampling2D
from keras.models import Model

data_iterator = data.as_numpy_iterator()
batch = data_iterator.next()

"""**Encoding Process**"""
input_img = Input(shape=(237, 237, 3))

# Conv1 #
x = Conv2D(filters = 32, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(input_img)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same')(x)

# Conv2 #
x = Conv2D(filters = 16, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same')(x) 

# Conv 3 #
x = Conv2D(filters = 8, kernel_size = (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
encoded = MaxPooling2D(pool_size = (2, 2), padding='same')(x)

"""**Decoding Process**"""
# DeConv1
x = Conv2D(8, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(encoded)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

# DeConv2
x = Conv2D(16, (3, 3), activation='relu', padding='same')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)

# Deconv3
x = Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='relu')(x)
x = UpSampling2D((2, 2))(x)
decoded = Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='sigmoid', padding='same')(x)

"""**Declare the Model**"""

autoencoder = Model(input_img, decoded)
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='binary_crossentropy')

# Train the model
autoencoder.fit(batch[0], batch[0],
                epochs=20,
                shuffle=False,
                #validation_data=(x_test, x_test)
               )
```

and this gives me the error I'm struggling with:

```
Epoch 1/20
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-70-62d669270126> in <module>
      2 autoencoder.fit(batch[0], batch[0],
      3                 epochs=20,
----> 4                 shuffle=False,
      5                 #validation_data=(x_test, x_test)
      6                )

1 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in autograph_handler(*args, **kwargs)
   1145           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
   1146             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
-> 1147               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
   1148             else:
   1149               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1021, in train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1010, in step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1000, in run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 860, in train_step
        loss = self.compute_loss(x, y, y_pred, sample_weight)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 919, in compute_loss
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py", line 201, in __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 141, in __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 245, in call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/losses.py", line 1932, in binary_crossentropy
        backend.binary_crossentropy(y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits),
    File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/keras/backend.py", line 5247, in binary_crossentropy
        return tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=target, logits=output)

    ValueError: `logits` and `labels` must have the same shape, received ((None, 236, 236, 1) vs (None, 237, 237, 3)).
```

Comment: Use a different loss function in `compile`. Maybe 'loss='mse'` since you are comparing two images, the input image with the output image

Answer (score 0):

[`binary_crossentropy`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/BinaryCrossentropy) loss should be used for binary classification problems. You are comparing two images, the input with the output image. So you could use for example [MeanSquaredError](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/losses/MeanSquaredError) as a loss function.

```
autoencoder.compile(optimizer='adadelta', loss='mse')
```

Comment: ok i updated that but got this error:
```
ValueError: Dimensions must be equal, but are 236 and 237 for '{{node mean_squared_error/SquaredDifference}} = SquaredDifference[T=DT_FLOAT](model/conv2d_6/Sigmoid, IteratorGetNext:1)' with input shapes: [32,236,236,1], [32,237,237,3].```

Comment: When you are up sampling, how do you want to get an odd shape number 237?

Comment: my images are 237x237 in size